# how to insert arabic letters in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, internationalization, arabic

I have looked all over the net trying to find a single tutorial about inserting arabic letters into mysql via HTML & PHP

my HTML page looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

and my php page is like this

```
// Connects to your Database 
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("castt") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'cp1256'"); 
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET cp1256');
```

when I browse the mysql DB, it appears like "?????"

any suggestion?

Answer (score 6):

You are making your database use `cp1256` while you declare your output as UTF-8. That can't work.

Replacing `cp1256` by `UTF8` might already help.

Comment: but as I mentioned above, I have tried your suggestion, it didn't work. thanx for replying

Comment: What happened? What chaacters did you get?

Comment: What collation is your database in?

Comment: Related good reading: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 4):

I have solved by adding

```
mysql_query("set character_set_server='utf8'");
mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
```

right after the connection

Answer (score 3):

Great it is working.......  :)
let me show you code.

**Step-1 Create database table**

```
CREATE TABLE `language_messages` (
  `lang_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `en` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `ar` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`lang_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

INSERT INTO `language_messages` VALUES (1, 'About Us', 'من نحن');
INSERT INTO `language_messages` VALUES (2, 'Contact Us', ' تواصل معنا ');
INSERT INTO `language_messages` VALUES (5, '', 'శ్రీనివాస్ తామాడా');
```

**Step-2 create connection**

```
$conn=mysql_connect(HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("set character_set_server='utf8'");
mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
```

**Step-3  View output in HTML page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!--<html  dir="rtl" lang="ar" xml:lang="ar" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php 

$sql = "select * from language_messages";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
        echo"<br />". $row['en'];   
        echo"<br />". $row['ar'];   
    }

?>
</body>
</html>
```